# How does mysqli_fetch_array work?

Tags: php

A while loop usually has code that tries to avoid an infinite loop. I don't understand how this works `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)`?
From the php manual, it says that mysqli_fetch_array returns an array per result row. So we are assigning here an array to the variable $row. Well I tried to replicate this:

```
$result_set = $database->query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)){
      some code
    }
```

with this:

```
$a = ["a","b","c"];
$num = 1;

while($row = $a){
 echo $num;
  $num++;
}
```

and I get an infinite loop. What am I missing?

Comment: One is getting results from an array one at a time until there are no more elements, the other is always assigning the array to a variable so it never is false. The second example needs to be wrapped in a function that iterates through the array and returns each element until there are no more.

Comment: But the above code works with $variable assignment. However, the replicate does not work.

Comment: I don't see you using `$row` here; what are we missing here? It's probably erroring out but you're not looking for those errors.

Comment: To further what @JohnConde said, you would have to use something like `foreach($a AS $row)` to replicate the results.

Comment: A more accurate replication would be `$a = function () { yield from ["a","b","c"]; };` or `$a = function () { foreach(["a","b","c"] as $value { yield $value;} };`

Comment: @JohnConde So once there are no more elements available, it returns null which ends the while loop?

Comment: @stepbystep correct

Answer (score 1):

In order to replicate the behavior of `mysqli_fetch_array()` with an array you create consider the following: first create an array of arrays:

```
$a = ["a"=>array(1,2,3),"b"=>array(4,5,6),"c"=>array(7,8,9)];
$num = 1;
```

One way (there is more than one way to skin this proverbial cat) is to use a `foreach()`loop to get and manipulate (echo) each row:

```
foreach($a AS $row){
 echo $num ."\n";
 $num++;
 echo $row[0] . " " . $row[1] . " " .$row[2] . "\n";
}
```

This returns just what you would expect, your number followed by the data in each row of `$a` [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/797c588644a8f04c069bf0ec770cc9f1dce922e0):

```
1
1 2 3
2
4 5 6
3
7 8 9
```

Once the loop has reached the end of the array it will exit, same as `mysqli_fetch_array()` which essentially says, "foreach result_set as row".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with `while` loop which is  like `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))`

```
 $a = ["a","b","c"];
    $num = 0;

    while($num < count($a)){         
        echo $a[$num]."\n";
        $num++;       
    }
```